# Should the removeAt() function remove the removing node’s pointer?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm a beginner in coding and recently studying linked list on JavaScript.

I am confused that while removing node, should I also change the removing node’s pointer to `null`?

`RemoveAt(index)` method is a custom method for removing the node at a specific index.

Example as below:

```
// remove node 
removeAt(index){
    // check if index is qualified
    if(index < 0 || index > this.length) return null;
    let current = this.head,
        prev = null,
        idx = 0;
    // if first node
    if(index===0){
        // point the head to next node
        this.head = current.next;
    }else{
        // else find the index
        while(idx++ < index){
            prev = current; // set prev node as current
            current = current.next; // and move current to the next node
        }
        // index finded, link prev.next & current.next
        prev.next = current.next;
    }
    this.length--;
}
```

Most of the linked list examples I saw in JS omitted this. I am wondering will it waste more memory?

Comment: *"...the removing node..."* Did you mean the *removed* node?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That what I mean. Sorry for bad English

Comment: Given the whole node object that you remove is typically garbage-collected right away, it doesn't matter whether it's garbage-collected with an object reference or a `null` value in its property. And no, both of them take the same amount of memory anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign `null` to `current`. It is a variable that is local to the function, so as soon as the function exits, there is no more reference to the removed node, and it can be garbage collected.

If outside of the function's context you happen to have another reference to the node that is removed, then the node will not be garbage collected. Assigning `null` to `current` will not change that situation.

Some coders may want to *isolate* the node however:

```
current.next = null;
```

This way, if there is somewhere still a reference to that node, there is no risk of walking from that node into the list, which may be undesired. On the other hand, it really is a code smell if outside of the function there is still a reference to the node that is removed, and it would get really smelly if that reference is still used to traverse along its `next` property. So if the overall code is doing the right thing, you don't really need to do `current.next = null` either.

Answer (score 0):

> ...while removing node, should I also change the removed node’s pointer to `null`? ... I am wondering will it waste more memory?

It's not necessary for memory management, no. (I think there's an argument for doing it for other reasons, but not memory management.) If you remove node A without clearing its pointer to node B, and nothing else refers to node A, then it's eligible for garbage collection. (And if you also remove B, the fact A still refers to it won't keep it in memory if nothing else has a reference to them; they'll both be eligible for garbage collection.)

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to do that, as it is you are freeing that part of memory by deleting the node, it doesn't matter what are contents of that freed node's data part or next part

Comment: The memory is freed by the node object being garbage-collected, not by "deleting" it.

Comment: yes, that's what I intended to say, GC happens because of the node getting removed/deleted, end result is memory being freed

Comment: *"you are freeing that part of memory"*: you really should rephrase this, as the code is **not** freeing the memory. It is not even sure that that memory will be freed soon. This is all up to the garbage collector.